# Android/Oculus Quest 2 - Kiosk Mode

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculusquest

I'm working at the moment on a delicate matter that is the implementation of some sort of  kiosk mode for Oculus Quest 2, that is not prebuilt for the device.

The Oculus Quest 2 is running on some 10.0 version of Android, but there's a huge Meta Operating System that is running on Android but redefines a lot of its behaviour.

Using the default Android Kiosk Mode solutions like LockTaskMode doesn't seem to do the trick.

One the biggest issue and the Key to the solution is in my opinion being able to capture the event triggered by the push on the Home button of the Oculus controller, which is actually a KEYCODE.FORWARD.
Because using this button while in a VR application makes an Oculus Overlay appear over the running Application and allows you to quit it, getting you back the Oculus Home.

The problem is that Android does not allow you to get the KeyEvent outside of a running activity.

---

I have 2 of my own applications to try solve this issue.

One is a device-owner app that allows me to do everything that I should need.
We'll call it test.service

The second is a Unity VR application that is supposed to become the Kiosk application which the user will be locked in, and also able to launch other applications from it and return to the Kiosk after closing them.
We'll call it test.home

I also developed a Android Library for this Unity app that allows me to override the Unity Main Activity in some ways and also communicate via intents to test.service.
We'll call it test.library

I spent a lot of time logging everyone that I could, unpackaging the Oculus Home apps, looking at their Overlay system etc... But still haven't found a way to override the native behaviour.

What I think I need:

- Some sort of way to capture the KeyEvent outside of an activity
- Or have my apps be launched on overlay of my Unity app, so that my Unity App Activity will still be accessible and intercept KeyEvent?
- Intercept Oculus intents et reroute them?
- Make my app as default Android Launcher, that I can do but it has no effect whatsoever

So I'm looking for any Android Expert insights on this matter...

Here are the logs for when you use the Home button of the Oculus Controller:

```
2022-11-07 16:47:55.916 15947-15947/? D/InputHooksJava: Callback: dispatchKeyEvent
2022-11-07 16:47:55.918 1381-2474/? I/ServiceInputManager: system button SetHomeButtonDownState 16443.4
2022-11-07 16:47:55.918 1381-2474/? I/ServiceInputManager: system button down, should reset recenter timer
2022-11-07 16:47:55.918 1381-2474/? I/ServiceInputManager: HOME BUTTON shared state changed:  hardware ID 2667197000331223313  UpdateCount: 29 
2022-11-07 16:47:55.918 1381-2474/? I/RecenterTimer: UpdateTimerData(16443.87 16444.37)
2022-11-07 16:47:56.002 15947-16092/? I/VrApi: FPS=90/90,Prd=30ms,Tear=0,Early=46,Stale=0,VSnc=0,Lat=-1,Fov=0D,CPU4/GPU=4/4,1478/525MHz,OC=FF,TA=0/0/0,SP=N/N/N,Mem=2092MHz,Free=2875MB,PLS=0,Temp=32.0C/0.0C,TW=2.39ms,App=5.64ms,GD=0.11ms,CPU&GPU=11.62ms,LCnt=4(DR0,LM2),GPU%=0.77,CPU%=0.33(W0.37),DSF=1.00,CFL=14.60/19.53
2022-11-07 16:47:56.091 15947-15947/? D/InputHooksJava: Callback: dispatchKeyEvent
2022-11-07 16:47:56.097 1381-2474/? I/ServiceInputManager: system button SetHomeButtonUpState 16443.6
2022-11-07 16:47:56.097 1381-2474/? I/ServiceInputManager: HOME BUTTON shared state changed:  hardware ID 2667197000331223313  UpdateCount: 30 
2022-11-07 16:47:56.097 1381-2474/? I/RecenterTimer: UpdateTimerData(-1.00 -1.00)
2022-11-07 16:47:56.282 862-13395/? W/[CT]: VEGA:MAP_TRACKING_HM: [Throttled count=22] Bad map tracking: map tracking failed @ Submap id = 0, version = 1357567886 with status: 2
2022-11-07 16:47:56.282 862-13395/? W/[CT]: VEGA:MAP_TRACKING_HM: [Throttled count=22] Map tracking did not run.
2022-11-07 16:47:56.282 862-13395/? I/[CT]: VEGA:PERCEPTUAL_HM: [Throttled count=22] Perceptual HM: no map tracking while exposing 6DoF. Delaying switch to 3DoF for 2.56 seconds.
2022-11-07 16:47:56.283 862-13395/? I/[CT]: VegaTracker: [Throttled count=22] VegaTracker::track returned 113 track measurement(s) 10 track-to-landmark association(s) and 15 closed track ID(s) while reporting poor tracking quality. (isTrackerHealthy = true, isMapTrackingHealthy = false)
2022-11-07 16:47:56.353 1381-2474/? I/ServiceInputManager: short system button press 16443.807692
2022-11-07 16:47:56.353 1381-2474/? I/ServiceInputManager: system event from short press 16443.807692
2022-11-07 16:47:56.353 1381-2474/? I/ServiceInputManager: ServiceInputManager::FireSystemButtonEvent queueing launch intent from service
2022-11-07 16:47:56.353 1381-2474/? I/ServiceInputManager: ServiceInputManager::FireSystemButtonEvent 'com.resolutiongames.baitsantacruz' Transition Type: 1
2022-11-07 16:47:56.353 1381-2474/? I/RecenterTimer: UpdateTimerData(-1.00 -1.00)
2022-11-07 16:47:56.364 1381-2474/? I/ServiceInputManager: ServiceInputManager::ProcessSystemButtonEvent launching intent from service 'com.resolutiongames.baitsantacruz' 1
2022-11-07 16:47:56.364 1381-2474/? I/ServiceInputManager: ServiceInputManager::ProcessSystemButtonEvent transitioning with a memory of the app name
2022-11-07 16:47:56.364 1381-2474/? I/SystemUtils_Internal: ovrSystemUtils::StartAnytimeUI: confirmQuit
2022-11-07 16:47:56.364 1381-2474/? D/SystemUtils: sendBroadcastIntent - action: 'com.oculus.vrshell.intent.action.LAUNCH' data: 'systemux://dialog/exit'intent_pkg: com.resolutiongames.baitsantacruz
2022-11-07 16:47:56.365 1381-2474/? D/SystemUtils: VR Shell isn't running.
2022-11-07 16:47:56.368 14877-14877/? D/[SEO] ShellControlBroadcastReceiver: onReceive with MainActivity native pointer 3554546032, action com.oculus.vrshell.intent.action.LAUNCH
2022-11-07 16:47:56.369 14877-14877/? E/[SEO] ShellApplication: Failed to verify identity of calling application for app launch flow. Bundle is missing handshake binder!
2022-11-07 16:47:56.371 14877-14877/? D/[SEO] ShellControlBroadcastReceiver: isLaunchAction = true, isTrustedAppLaunch = false
2022-11-07 16:47:56.371 14877-14877/? D/[SEO] NavigationRouter: Data URI is systemux://dialog/exit
2022-11-07 16:47:56.373 14877-14877/? E/[SEO] ShellControlBroadcastReceiver: Submitting as launch intent
2022-11-07 16:47:56.373 14877-14877/? D/[SEO] NavigationRouter: Data URI is systemux://dialog/exit
2022-11-07 16:47:56.373 14877-14877/? D/[SEO] NavigationRouter: systemUxRouteString = systemux://dialog/exit
2022-11-07 16:47:56.374 14877-14877/? D/[SEO] NavigationRouter: systemUXRoute = EXIT_TO_HOME(systemux://dialog/exit)
2022-11-07 16:47:56.375 14877-14877/? D/[SEO] NavigationRouter: shouldLaunchAsOverlay
2022-11-07 16:47:56.376 14877-14877/? D/[SEO] NavigationRouter: Data URI is systemux://dialog/exit
2022-11-07 16:47:56.376 14877-14877/? I/[SEO] RssdkHelperJNI: Java_com_oculus_common_navigation_RssdkHelper_nativeGetCurrentPackageInfo
2022-11-07 16:47:56.376 14877-14877/? I/[SEO] RssdkHelperJNI: NativeGetCurrentPackageInfo - str combined: 'com.resolutiongames.baitsantacruz'
2022-11-07 16:47:56.376 14877-14877/? D/[SEO] NavigationRouter: shouldLaunchAsOverlay == true (focus aware and valid route
2022-11-07 16:47:56.377 14705-14705/? I/[OAO] ShellOverlayService: onStartCommand(): Intent { act=com.oculus.vrshell.intent.action.LAUNCH flg=0x10010030 pkg=com.oculus.vrshell cmp=com.oculus.vrshell/.ShellOverlayService (has extras) }
2022-11-07 16:47:56.377 14705-14705/? I/[OAO] ShellOverlayServiceJNI: NativeWake
2022-11-07 16:47:56.378 14705-14705/? I/[OAO] ShellOverlayMain: WakeVrThread
2022-11-07 16:47:56.378 14705-14705/? I/[OAO] ShellOverlayMain: WakeVrThread - notifying vr thread
2022-11-07 16:47:56.384 14705-14764/? I/[OAO] ShellOverlayApp: 0xc07f3c20 msg: broadcastIntent:
    intent_pkg = com.resolutiongames.baitsantacruz
    intent_data = systemux://dialog/exit
    intent_action = com.oculus.vrshell.intent.action.LAUNCH
    origin_hint = [OAO] ShellOverlayService:onStartCommand
2022-11-07 16:47:56.385 14705-14764/? I/[OAO] ShellOverlayApp: ProcessMessage_Broadcast: com.oculus.vrshell.intent.action.LAUNCH
2022-11-07 16:47:56.385 14705-14764/? I/[OAO] OverlayFlowController: ShellControl::BroadcastIntent::Launch
2022-11-07 16:47:56.385 14705-14764/? I/[OAO] OverlayFlowController: SetPendingLaunchFromIntent - target=systemux://dialog/exit, return=com.resolutiongames.baitsantacruz, uri=, launchingComponent=com.oculus.vrshell.intent.action.LAUNCH
2022-11-07 16:47:56.385 14705-14764/? I/[OAO] OverlayFlowController: exclusiveDialogFlow Parse result:  0
2022-11-07 16:47:56.385 14705-14764/? I/[OAO] OverlayGuardianFlow: OverlayGuardianFlow::ParseShellUri IsRequestingActivation() = 0
2022-11-07 16:47:56.385 14705-14764/? I/[OAO] OverlayGuardianFlow: OverlayGuardianFlow::ParseShellUri shellGuardianState = 0
2022-11-07 16:47:56.385 14705-14764/? I/[OAO] GuardianController: SETUP STATE1 ACTIVE: GUARDIAN_SYSTEM_GUARDIAN_VISIBLE
2022-11-07 16:47:56.385 14705-14764/? I/[OAO] GuardianController: SETUP STATE1 ACTIVE: GUARDIAN_SYSTEM_GUARDIAN_VALID
2022-11-07 16:47:56.385 14705-14764/? I/[OAO] GuardianController: SETUP STATE2 ACTIVE: GUARDIAN_SYSTEM_2_DIRECTIONAL_PASSTHROUGH_ENABLED
2022-11-07 16:47:56.385 14705-14764/? I/[OAO] OverlayFlowController: Guardian Parse result:  0
2022-11-07 16:47:56.385 14705-14764/? I/[OAO] OverlayFlowController: KeyboardFlow Parse result:  0
2022-11-07 16:47:56.385 14705-14764/? I/[OAO] OverlayFlowController: isExternalWebTask:  0
2022-11-07 16:47:56.385 14705-14764/? I/[OAO] DialogControllerManager: Dialog parsed URI, scheme = systemux, host = dialog, path = exit
2022-11-07 16:47:56.385 14705-14764/? W/[OAO] DialogControllerManager: Invalid pending dialog detected systemux://dialog/exit.
2022-11-07 16:47:56.385 14705-14764/? I/[OAO] PanelAppLaunchInfo: PanelAppLaunchInfo componentString:com.oculus.systemux/com.oculus.panelapp.destinationui.DestinationUiPanelService packageName:com.oculus.systemux serviceName:com.oculus.panelapp.destinationui.DestinationUiPanelService componentName:com.oculus.systemux/com.oculus.panelapp.destinationui.DestinationUiPanelService
2022-11-07 16:47:56.385 14705-14764/? I/[OAO] HostPlatform: Retrieving component launch information for package (com.oculus.systemux) and service (com.oculus.panelapp.destinationui.DestinationUiPanelService)
2022-11-07 16:47:56.388 14705-14764/? I/[OAO] HostPlatform: Is valid panel service component for package (com.oculus.systemux) and service (com.oculus.panelapp.destinationui.DestinationUiPanelService) - true
2022-11-07 16:47:56.388 14705-14764/? I/[OAO] OverlayDesktopFlow: Processing pending launch for component systemux://dialog/exit with uri .
2022-11-07 16:47:56.388 14705-14764/? I/[OAO] OverlayDesktopFlow: Creating panel app for component com.oculus.systemux/com.oculus.panelapp.destinationui.DestinationUiPanelService with initial uri .
2022-11-07 16:47:56.388 14705-14764/? I/[OAO] LaunchController: System UX, targetComponent = systemux://dialog/exit, uri = , returnComponent = com.resolutiongames.baitsantacruz
2022-11-07 16:47:56.388 14705-14764/? I/[OAO] PanelAppLaunchInfo: PanelAppLaunchInfo componentString:com.oculus.systemux/com.oculus.panelapp.destinationui.DestinationUiPanelService packageName:com.oculus.systemux serviceName:com.oculus.panelapp.destinationui.DestinationUiPanelService componentName:com.oculus.systemux/com.oculus.panelapp.destinationui.DestinationUiPanelService
2022-11-07 16:47:56.389 14705-14764/? I/[OAO] HostPlatform: Retrieving component launch information for package (com.oculus.systemux) and service (com.oculus.panelapp.destinationui.DestinationUiPanelService)
2022-11-07 16:47:56.391 14705-14764/? I/[OAO] HostPlatform: Is valid panel service component for package (com.oculus.systemux) and service (com.oculus.panelapp.destinationui.DestinationUiPanelService) - true
2022-11-07 16:47:56.391 14705-14764/? I/[OAO] LaunchController: Registering Pending Launch of type ShellApplication with com.oculus.systemux/com.oculus.panelapp.destinationui.DestinationUiPanelService, overwriting existing launch false, of type None.
2022-11-07 16:47:56.391 14705-14764/? I/[OAO] OverlayDesktopFlow: OverlayDesktopFlow::ParseShellUri requesting activationType:1
2022-11-07 16:47:56.391 14705-14764/? I/[OAO] OverlayFlowController: DesktopFlow Parse result:  1
2022-11-07 16:47:56.391 14705-14764/? I/[OAO] OverlayFlowController: Setting lastNonSystemPackageName to com.resolutiongames.baitsantacruz
2022-11-07 16:47:56.391 14705-14764/? I/[OAO] OverlayFlowController: Setting primaryAppComponent = com.resolutiongames.baitsantacruz
2022-11-07 16:47:56.391 14705-14764/? I/[OAO] FlowController: UpdateActiveFlow from (none) to OverlayDesktopFlow
2022-11-07 16:47:56.391 14705-14764/? I/[OAO] OverlayDesktopFlow: Activated
2022-11-07 16:47:56.391 14705-14764/? I/[OAO] DesktopPanelController: Foreground desktop Multi-app
2022-11-07 16:47:56.391 14705-14764/? I/[OAO] ShellOverlayApp: ResolveInteractionState: change from None to InputFocus
2022-11-07 16:47:56.391 14705-14764/? D/[OAO] ShellApplication: setOverlayInputFocus: inputFocus=true shouldSupportIME=false
2022-11-07 16:47:56.391 14705-14764/? D/[OAO] BaseOverlayService: setOverlayInputFocus : entrypoint - inputFocus=true shouldSupportIME=false
2022-11-07 16:47:56.391 14705-14764/? I/[OAO] SystemAssistant: OnModeChanged from ImmersiveAppFocused to Paused
2022-11-07 16:47:56.391 14705-14705/? D/[OAO] BaseOverlayService: attachServiceWindowView shouldSupportIME:false
2022-11-07 16:47:56.391 14705-14764/? I/[OAO] ShellOverlayApp: EnterVrMode
2022-11-07 16:47:56.392 14705-14764/? D/[OAO] ShellApplication: setOverlayInputFocus: inputFocus=true shouldSupportIME=false
2022-11-07 16:47:56.392 14705-14764/? D/[OAO] BaseOverlayService: setOverlayInputFocus : entrypoint - inputFocus=true shouldSupportIME=false
2022-11-07 16:47:56.392 14705-14764/? I/[OAO] SystemAssistant: OnModeChanged requested with no change Paused
2022-11-07 16:47:56.392 14705-14764/? I/[OAO] VrPlatformOpenXr: Setting clock levels to cpu=2, gpu=4
2022-11-07 16:47:56.392 14705-14764/? I/[OAO] VrPlatformOpenXr: Setting perf thread tids to main=14764, render=unset
2022-11-07 16:47:56.392 14705-14764/? I/OpenXR: ------------ xrBeginSession [start] -----------
2022-11-07 16:47:56.392 14705-14764/? I/VrRuntimeClient: Tracing is disabled
2022-11-07 16:47:56.392 14705-14764/? I/VrRuntimeClient: SysProp debug mode is disabled on Client side
2022-11-07 16:47:56.394 14705-14764/? D/VrApi: targetSDKVersion 29
2022-11-07 16:47:56.398 14705-14764/? I/VrRuntimeClient: DEVICE MODEL NUMBER = Quest 2
2022-11-07 16:47:56.398 14705-14764/? I/VrRuntimeClient: DEVICE BUILD NAME = user-47421700667400000
2022-11-07 16:47:56.398 14705-14764/? I/VrRuntimeClient: DEVICE BUILD TYPE = user
2022-11-07 16:47:56.398 14705-14764/? I/VrRuntimeClient: DEVICE OS VERSION = 10
2022-11-07 16:47:56.398 14705-14764/? I/VrRuntimeClient: API LOADER VERSION = 1.0.22
2022-11-07 16:47:56.398 14705-14764/? I/VrRuntimeClient: RUNTIME API VERSION = 1.0.24
2022-11-07 16:47:56.399 14705-14764/? I/VrRuntimeClient: RUNTIME VERSION = 46.0.0.226.0 Sep  6 2022 02:18:30 RELEASE
2022-11-07 16:47:56.399 14705-14764/? I/VrRuntimeClient: APP NAME = Oculus App Runtime
2022-11-07 16:47:56.399 14705-14764/? I/VrRuntimeClient: APP VERSION = 46.0.0.226.0 versionCode 406523266 internalVersionName 46.0.0.226.0.5b7f9b66a2a2 2022_10_06_18_22
2022-11-07 16:47:56.399 14705-14764/? I/VrRuntimeClient: APP VR TYPE = vr_only
2022-11-07 16:47:56.399 14705-14764/? I/VrRuntimeClient: APP MODE TYPE = VR
2022-11-07 16:47:56.399 14705-14764/? I/VrRuntimeClient: APP PACKAGE NAME = com.oculus.vrshell
2022-11-07 16:47:56.399 14705-14764/? I/VrRuntimeClient: APP ACTIVITY CLASS = com.oculus.vrshell.ShellOverlayService
2022-11-07 16:47:56.399 14705-14764/? I/Sensor: OSSDKTRACKING Initializing head tracking
2022-11-07 16:47:56.399 14705-14764/? I/Sensor: OSSDKTRACKING Head tracker != nullpointer 0xbe28cd68, 1
2022-11-07 16:47:56.399 14705-14764/? I/Sensor: OSSDKTRACKING Initializing controller tracking
2022-11-07 16:47:56.399 14705-14764/? I/Sensor: OSSDKTRACKING Controller tracker != nullpointer 0xbe28cdc0, 1
2022-11-07 16:47:56.399 14705-14764/? D/BatteryReceiver: Registering battery receiver
2022-11-07 16:47:56.401 14705-14764/? D/HeadsetReceiver: getCurrentHeadsetState: false
2022-11-07 16:47:56.401 14705-14764/? I/DeviceStatus: nativeHeadsetEvent(0)
2022-11-07 16:47:56.401 1073-4287/? E/WindowManager: App trying to use insecure INPUT_FEATURE_NO_INPUT_CHANNEL flag. Ignoring
2022-11-07 16:47:56.402 14705-14764/? I/VrRuntimeClient: SetCompositorClientFeatureFlag ClientFeatureFlag 0 
2022-11-07 16:47:56.402 14705-14764/? I/LogTimer: CPUTIME: VrRuntimeClient_BeginSession took 10.0890 ms
2022-11-07 16:47:56.403 1381-1381/? I/ClientMgr: FocusedWindowChanged: found matching overlay client: 1226683458
2022-11-07 16:47:56.403 1381-1381/? I/ClientMgr: FocusedClient changed.
2022-11-07 16:47:56.403 1381-1381/? I/ClientMgr: ClientMgr::SetFocusedClient: 14705:com.oculus.vrshell type 1
2022-11-07 16:47:56.403 1381-1381/? I/ClientMgr: SetFocusedPackageName - packageName com.oculus.vrshell processName com.oculus.vrshell:Overlay clientId 1226683458 clientPid 14705
2022-11-07 16:47:56.404 13631-13631/? D/[SUI] ActivityManagerUtilsHelper: onFocusedWindowChanged: Instance: com.oculus.panelapp.anytimeui.utils.ActivityManagerUtilsHelper@2aa9f36, topWindowUid: 10026, focusedApp: com.oculus.vrshell, previousApp: com.resolutiongames.baitsantacruz
2022-11-07 16:47:56.404 1381-1381/? I/VrRuntimeService: RuntimeIPC: SendFocusChangeEventToAllClients: PostClientEvent SUCCESS: com.oculus.vrshell:com.oculus.vrshell:14877, com.oculus.vrshell, com.oculus.vrshell:Overlay
2022-11-07 16:47:56.404 1381-1381/? I/VrRuntimeService: RuntimeIPC: SendFocusChangeEventToAllClients: PostClientEvent SUCCESS: com.resolutiongames.baitsantacruz:com.resolutiongames.baitsantacruz:15947, com.oculus.vrshell, com.oculus.vrshell:Overlay
2022-11-07 16:47:56.404 1381-1381/? I/VrRuntimeService: RuntimeIPC: SendFocusChangeEventToAllClients: PostClientEvent SUCCESS: com.oculus.shellenv:com.oculus.shellenv:14850, com.oculus.vrshell, com.oculus.vrshell:Overlay
2022-11-07 16:47:56.404 1381-1381/? I/VrRuntimeService: RuntimeIPC: SendFocusChangeEventToAllClients: PostClientEvent SUCCESS: com.oculus.vrshell:com.oculus.vrshell:Overlay:14705, com.oculus.vrshell, com.oculus.vrshell:Overlay
2022-11-07 16:47:56.404 1381-1381/? I/VrRuntimeService: RuntimeIPC: SendFocusChangeEventToAllClients: PostClientEvent SUCCESS: com.oculus.mrservice:com.oculus.mrservice:1709, com.oculus.vrshell, com.oculus.vrshell:Overlay
2022-11-07 16:47:56.404 1381-1381/? I/VrRuntimeService: RuntimeIPC: SendFocusChangeEventToAllClients: PostClientEvent SUCCESS: com.oculus.guardian:com.oculus.vrguardianservice:2782, com.oculus.vrshell, com.oculus.vrshell:Overlay
2022-11-07 16:47:56.404 13631-13631/? D/[SUI] ActivityManagerUtilsHelper: onFocusedWindowChanged: Instance: com.oculus.panelapp.anytimeui.utils.ActivityManagerUtilsHelper@493d1a9, topWindowUid: 10026, focusedApp: com.oculus.vrshell, previousApp: com.resolutiongames.baitsantacruz
2022-11-07 16:47:56.405 13631-13631/? D/[SUI] ActivityManagerUtilsHelper: onFocusedWindowChanged: Instance: com.oculus.panelapp.anytimeui.utils.ActivityManagerUtilsHelper@a3bb2f3, topWindowUid: 10026, focusedApp: com.oculus.vrshell, previousApp: com.resolutiongames.baitsantacruz
2022-11-07 16:47:56.407 14705-14764/? I/ClientInputInterface: DEADRECKONING SetControllerTrackingExtendedDeadreckoning 0
2022-11-07 16:47:56.407 14705-14764/? I/ClientInputSettings: HANDTRACKING package name is com.oculus.vrshell
2022-11-07 16:47:56.408 862-1210/? W/TrackingService: attachClient: found client in attached list
2022-11-07 16:47:56.408 862-4239/? W/TrackingService: attachClient: found client in attached list
2022-11-07 16:47:56.409 862-4239/? D/TrackingService: getSharedMemory: com.oculus.systemdriver, Controller
2022-11-07 16:47:56.410 862-4239/? W/TrackingService: attachClient: found client in attached list
2022-11-07 16:47:56.411 15947-15970/? E/OsSdk: error getting shared memory region, memory type: Controller, failed with Status(-1, EX_SECURITY): 'requested shared memory region when not registered/focused'
2022-11-07 16:47:56.412 15947-15970/? I/VrRuntimeClient: Client has lost focus.
2022-11-07 16:47:56.412 15947-15970/? I/OpenXR: PostSessionStateChange: XR_SESSION_STATE_FOCUSED -> XR_SESSION_STATE_VISIBLE
2022-11-07 16:47:56.413 15947-15970/? I/OVRPlugin: [XR_SESSION] XrEventDataSessionStateChanged: state XR_SESSION_STATE_FOCUSED->XR_SESSION_STATE_VISIBLE session=144115188075855898 time=16443867147160
2022-11-07 16:47:56.413 15947-15970/? D/OVRPlugin: [XR_SESSION] ... running 1 visible 1 focused 0
2022-11-07 16:47:56.413 14705-14705/? D/[OAO] BaseOverlayService: setOverlayInputFocus : completed - inputFocus=true shouldSupportIME=false actionTaken:true
2022-11-07 16:47:56.413 862-4239/? D/TrackingService: getSharedMemory: com.oculus.guardian, Controller
2022-11-07 16:47:56.414 14705-14705/? D/[OAO] BaseOverlayService: attachServiceWindowView shouldSupportIME:false
2022-11-07 16:47:56.414 14705-14705/? D/[OAO] BaseOverlayService: setOverlayInputFocus : completed - inputFocus=true shouldSupportIME=false actionTaken:false
2022-11-07 16:47:56.415 862-4239/? W/TrackingService: attachClient: found client in attached list
2022-11-07 16:47:56.416 2058-2506/? W/DeviceConfigUtil: Try to get config param "oculus_shared_social:oculus_messenger_reauth_removal" before Device Config has subscribed to the service.
2022-11-07 16:47:56.416 15947-15970/? E/OsSdk: error getting shared memory region, memory type: Controller, failed with Status(-1, EX_SECURITY): 'requested shared memory region when not registered/focused'
2022-11-07 16:47:56.418 14705-14764/? I/ClientInputSettings: HANDTRACKING: Manifest Permission request for com.oculus.vrshell
2022-11-07 16:47:56.419 2058-2507/? W/OVRLibrary: null cursor received for query content://com.oculus.ocms.library/apps/com.oculus.vrshell
2022-11-07 16:47:56.421 15947-15970/? E/OsSdk: error getting shared memory region, memory type: Controller, failed with Status(-1, EX_SECURITY): 'requested shared memory region when not registered/focused'
2022-11-07 16:47:56.422 14705-14764/? I/ClientInputSettings: HANDTRACKING:  'com.oculus.vrshell' Is hands or controller.
2022-11-07 16:47:56.422 14705-14764/? I/ClientInputSettings: HANDTRACKING: feature flag set to 2
2022-11-07 16:47:56.422 14705-14764/? I/ClientInputInterface: HANDTRACKING sethandmanifest 2
2022-11-07 16:47:56.423 14705-14764/? D/InputHooksJava: Enabling Java Input Hooks
2022-11-07 16:47:56.423 14705-14764/? W/InputHooksJava: Unable to enable input hooks on a non-Activity Context
2022-11-07 16:47:56.423 14705-14764/? I/InputDeviceManager: ovrInputDeviceManager::Initialize
2022-11-07 16:47:56.423 14705-14764/? I/Distortion: Initializing Mesh Decenter Correction
2022-11-07 16:47:56.427 15947-15947/? D/InputHooksJava: Callback: onWindowFocusChanged
2022-11-07 16:47:56.420 862-4239/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) Binder:862_4 identical 1 line
2022-11-07 16:47:56.426 862-4239/? W/TrackingService: attachClient: found client in attached list
2022-11-07 16:47:56.427 862-1210/? W/TrackingService: attachClient: found client in attached list
2022-11-07 16:47:56.427 850-5652/? E/CalibrationProvider: loadCalibration(LDISP_SN) failed: Calibration store didn't load any info
2022-11-07 16:47:56.429 862-1210/? D/TrackingService: getSharedMemory: com.oculus.vrshell, Controller
2022-11-07 16:47:56.430 14705-16207/? I/InputDevice_TrackedRemote: REMOTE: Hand=2 IndexAnalog=0.00 GripAnalog=0.00 Buttons=0x00000000
2022-11-07 16:47:56.430 14705-16207/? I/InputDeviceManager: HANDTRACKING Pointer filter profile changed to: 0
2022-11-07 16:47:56.430 14705-16207/? I/InputDeviceManager: HANDTRACKING Pointer filter profile changed to: 0
2022-11-07 16:47:56.430 14705-16207/? I/InputDeviceManager: HANDTRACKING Root pose filter profile changed for (version, freq) to (2, 1) from (1,2)
2022-11-07 16:47:56.430 15947-15970/? E/OsSdk: error getting shared memory region, memory type: Controller, failed with Status(-1, EX_SECURITY): 'requested shared memory region when not registered/focused'
2022-11-07 16:47:56.432 2058-2058/? I/OVRMediaServiceManager: Sending onAppStart (com.resolutiongames.baitsantacruz) to SocialPlatform (com.oculus.socialplatform)
2022-11-07 16:47:56.433 14705-14705/? D/KeyboardInputMethodService: onFinishInput
2022-11-07 16:47:56.435 862-4239/? W/TrackingService: attachClient: found client in attached list
2022-11-07 16:47:56.436 850-5652/? E/CalibrationProvider: loadCalibration(RDISP_SN) failed: Calibration store didn't load any info
2022-11-07 16:47:56.437 15947-15970/? E/OsSdk: error getting shared memory region, memory type: Controller, failed with Status(-1, EX_SECURITY): 'requested shared memory region when not registered/focused'
2022-11-07 16:47:56.443 862-13395/? W/[CT]: FrameToFrameTrackerHelper: Low ratio of valid tracks for available capacity (131/300=0.44<0.50). Verify corner detection and track creation!
2022-11-07 16:47:56.443 15947-15970/? E/OsSdk: error getting shared memory region, memory type: Controller, failed with Status(-1, EX_SECURITY): 'requested shared memory region when not registered/focused'
2022-11-07 16:47:56.444 14705-14764/? I/Distortion: SetLensPositions - iad=0.0678584, left offset=0.00211084,-0.00129752, right offset=-0.00234671,-0.00159407
2022-11-07 16:47:56.444 14705-14764/? I/Distortion: Initializing Mesh Decenter Correction
2022-11-07 16:47:56.449 15947-15970/? E/OsSdk: error getting shared memory region, memory type: Controller, failed with Status(-1, EX_SECURITY): 'requested shared memory region when not registered/focused'
2022-11-07 16:47:56.452 850-5652/? E/CalibrationProvider: loadCalibration(LDISP_SN) failed: Calibration store didn't load any info
2022-11-07 16:47:56.453 850-5652/? E/CalibrationProvider: loadCalibration(RDISP_SN) failed: Calibration store didn't load any info
2022-11-07 16:47:56.454 14705-14764/? I/Distortion: SetLensPositions - iad=0.0678584, left offset=0.00211084,-0.00129752, right offset=-0.00234671,-0.00159407
2022-11-07 16:47:56.455 1654-1654/? D/OculusNotificationListenerService: Notification posted: 0|android|0|com.android.server.wm.AlertWindowNotification - com.oculus.vrshell|1000
2022-11-07 16:47:56.455 14705-14764/? I/Distortion: Created custom distortion mesh.
2022-11-07 16:47:56.455 14705-14764/? I/PhaseSync: PhaseSync::PhaseSync PaddingLowerLimit 0.350000 StandardDeviations 2.000000 PaddingUpperLimit 0.750000 on instance 3
2022-11-07 16:47:56.455 14705-14764/? I/VrRuntimeClient: PhaseSync Instance created
2022-11-07 16:47:56.455 1381-14759/? I/VrRuntimeService: RuntimeServiceSDKServer::EnableRendering: 0x0, 0, com.oculus.vrshell:Overlay
2022-11-07 16:47:56.455 1381-14759/? I/ClientMgr: EnableRendering2: invalid clientWindow, testing uid/pid
2022-11-07 16:47:56.455 1381-14759/? I/ClientMgr: EnableRendering2: matched uid: 10026 and pid: 14705 
2022-11-07 16:47:56.455 1381-14759/? I/ClientMgr: EnableRendering2: Calling SetFocusedClient: 1226683458
2022-11-07 16:47:56.455 1381-14759/? I/ClientMgr: ClientMgr::SetFocusedClient: 14705:com.oculus.vrshell type 1
2022-11-07 16:47:56.455 1381-14759/? I/ClientMgr: SetFocusedPackageName - packageName com.oculus.vrshell processName com.oculus.vrshell:Overlay clientId 1226683458 clientPid 14705
2022-11-07 16:47:56.455 1381-14759/? I/ClientMgr: ClientMgr::EnableRendering 14705:com.oculus.vrshell : type 1 comp-id 20: enable
2022-11-07 16:47:56.455 1381-14759/? I/CompositorClientMgr: Enable client 20
2022-11-07 16:47:56.455 1381-14759/? I/VrRuntimeServer: EnableCompositorClient client(20): layer placement(2147483647) flags(0) sm(0x76e2b54010)
2022-11-07 16:47:56.455 1381-14759/? I/CompositorVR: CheckDebuggerConnected: debugger 0
2022-11-07 16:47:56.456 1381-14759/? I/VrRuntimeServer: SysProp debug mode is disabled on Server side
2022-11-07 16:47:56.456 1381-14759/? I/UnifiedTelemetryWrapper: Started UT session render:com.oculus.vrshell:Overlay
2022-11-07 16:47:56.456 14705-14764/? I/VrApi: OVR::Stats thread started
2022-11-07 16:47:56.456 14705-14764/? I/XrRuntimeUtils: XrRuntimeUtils::BeginSession
2022-11-07 16:47:56.456 14705-14764/? I/XrRuntimeSystem_Client: BeginSession
2022-11-07 16:47:56.456 14705-14764/? I/OpenXR: ------------ xrBeginSession [end] -----------
2022-11-07 16:47:56.457 1709-14806/? I/[CT]: MIXEDREALITY: MrFeatureStatus: Client status changed from Paused to Started.
2022-11-07 16:47:56.457 1709-14806/? I/[CT]: MIXEDREALITY: MrFeatureStatus: Target status Started, CurrentStatus: Paused
2022-11-07 16:47:56.457 1709-14806/? I/[CT]: MIXEDREALITY: MrFeatureStatus: Operation chain: Start
2022-11-07 16:47:56.457 1709-14806/? I/[CT]: MIXEDREALITY: MrFeatureStatus: Global status changed from Paused to Started.
```